# ILoggingBuilder Logging LogLevel in Appsettings Json doesn't seem to be acknowledged in Azure Log Stream or Blob Log

Tags: c#, azure, logging, asp.net-core-2.1

I've created a new .net core 2.1 web app and deployed to Azure and Log Stream and and Application Logging to Blob storage don't seem to be honoring my Logging configuration.

I created a new Solution with a new project in Visual Studio 2019 for a .net core 2.1 web app. In the home controller Index route, we added a line log some information that looks like this:

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("=========================================");
    _logger.LogError("=========================================");
    return View();
}
```

And in the `appsettings.Development.json` we've set the `LogLevel` for System and Microsoft to "Error".

What I expect is behavior in Azure to be what it is when ran locally.  Locally when accessing the index route and having the appsettings.Development.json LogLevel for System and Microsoft set to "Information" We see this output in the Debug output window:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   starting HTTP/1.1 GET http//localhost:44378/
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information:
>   Identity.Application was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect
>   ticket failed
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", page = "",
>   area = ""}. Executing controller action with signature
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller
>   LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController (LoggingTest).
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executing action method LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (LoggingTest) - Validation state: Valid
>   LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController:Information:
>   ========================================= LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController:Error:
>   ========================================= Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executed action method LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (LoggingTest), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in
>   7.9475ms. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information:
>   Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information:
>   Executed ViewResult - view Index executed in 11.4824ms.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executed action LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (LoggingTest) in 37.629ms
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 54.1369ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8

And when System and Microsoft are set to "Error":

> LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController:Information: 
>   ========================================= LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController:Error: 
>   .=========================================

We want this to be the case to be our output to our LogStream and Logs.  We essentially don't want the EfCore and other Microsoft related information in the log unless its of LogLevel "Error". But we want our logs of Level "Information" to be logged.

After publishing to Azure and setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to development to use the same Appsettings setup. The log stream and blob for the log look like this after calling the index:

> 2019-05-17 15:57:24.844 +00:00 [Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting
>   HTTP/1.1 GET http//loggingtest20190517104201.azurewebsites.net/
>   2019-05-17 15:57:24.844 +00:00 [Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Route
>   matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", page = "", area =
>   ""}. Executing action LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (LoggingTest) 2019-05-17 15:57:24.844 +00:00 [Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing
>   action method LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (LoggingTest) - Validation state: Valid 2019-05-17 15:57:24.844 +00:00
>   [Information] LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController:
>   ========================================= 2019-05-17 15:57:24.845 +00:00 [Error] LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController: ========================================= 2019-05-17 15:57:24.845 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed
>   action method LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (LoggingTest), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in
>   0.0635ms. 2019-05-17 15:57:24.845 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Executing
>   ViewResult, running view Index. 2019-05-17 15:57:24.845 +00:00
>   [Information]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Executed
>   ViewResult - view Index executed in 0.8902ms. 2019-05-17 15:57:24.845
>   +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed
>   action LoggingTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index (LoggingTest) in
>   1.0913ms 2019-05-17 15:57:24.846 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in
>   1.4542ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8 2019-05-17 15:57:24.941 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request
>   starting HTTP/1.1 GET
>
> The rest of log removed for brevity...

Heres my appsettings.development.json file:

> ```
> {
>   "Logging": {
>     "LogLevel": {
>       "Default": "Debug",
>       "System": "Error",
>       "Microsoft": "Error"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Heres my appsettings.json file:

> ```
> {
>   "ConnectionStrings": {
>     "DefaultConnection": "Removed"
>   }, 
>   "AllowedHosts": "*"
> }
> ```

Environement Variable set in Azure Web App:

[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smk2h.png)

The Program.cs and Startup.cs are unmodified from the project template.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Why are my Log Levels not being honored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally able to make it work by placing these setting in my appsettings.development.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Error"
    },
    "AzureAppServicesBlob": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "AzureAppServicesFile": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used the following to configure the Azure log Provider

```
"AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings": {
  "Microsoft": "Warning"
}
```

But reviewing the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.azureappservices.azureappservicesdiagnosticssettings?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that provider is now obsolete and is replaced with  AzureFileLoggerOptions and AzureBlobLoggerOptions (see [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#azure-app-service-provider)).

Though, I have not tested either of those configuration options to know if they work the same.

Comment: Though obsolete.  I did try it but it had no effect.  But even worse, I have cleared providers and have turned off logging and still see my blob and log stream filled with information!  Both configure logging setups below dont' seem to have any effect:

`           logBuilder.AddFilter((provider, category, logLevel) =>
            {
                return false;
            }).ClearProviders();
        })"

  .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error))`