# ASP.NET Core 3.1, logging only specific messages to Azure Log Stream Console

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API running on Microsoft Azure App Service.

I have set up an `ILogger` into the app and I use it extensively to monitor the behavior of the API. I would like to be able to see those messages real time into the Azure Log Stream of the app portal.

I managed to get logs after registering the `AzureWebAppDiagnostics` into `Program.cs` as follows:

```
 public class Program
 {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
       }
    }
```

The problem is that messages I logged explicitly, using

```
logger.LogInformation("whatever message")
```

are mixed with system messages and becomes flooded: Entity Framework commands, `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` messages, and multiple other informative messages.

How can I set up the system in a way that I get only error/warning messages from the system, and informative messages from my app code.

I tried to change the `appsettings.json` as follows, but it seems to have no effect at all :

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error",
      "Microsoft.*": "Error",
      "System": "Error",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*": "Warning" 
    }
  }
```

I deleted as well the `appsettings.development.json` file just in case, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633749/why-asp-net-core-logging-everything).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, after throrough researches, the solution was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190165/iloggingbuilder-logging-loglevel-in-appsettings-json-doesnt-seem-to-be-acknowle)

You need to add AzureAppServicesBlob and AzureAppServicesFile configuration into your configuration file, they seem to be the one taken into account by the Azure Log Stream.

So I added the following part :

```
"AzureAppServicesBlob": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Error",
    "System": "Error"
  }
},
"AzureAppServicesFile": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Error",
    "System": "Error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not wildcarded in the configuration. It's simply a namespace prefix: use  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` as the property name.

Comment: This is not why it's not working, I can see Hosting.Lifetime information logs despite the namespace is correct.